# How to open waze carpool app from swift code?

Tags: ios, deeplink, waze

There is a waze:// url that open the waze standard app but I can't find a carpool deeplink to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All supported deeplink documentation for waze are in [here](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/)
2. [This](https://developers.google.com/waze/intro-transport) documentation describes what features are supported by deeplink and waze sdk.

After playing with some [link](https://www.waze.com/carpool#download) (within iPhone safari browser) which invoke the waze carpoll app install, i figure out two undocumented way.

1. using `com.waze.rider://`
2. using `wazerider://`

The first one is more robust and not likely to be changed in near future.

NB: Don't forget to add these into your `info.plist` > `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`.

Comment: Thanks but I've read this guide 2 times and did not found carpool content

Comment: what exactly you mean by carpool content ?

Comment: If it's not in the documentation, then it's not probably supported.

Comment: It's about this app https://www.waze.com/carpool

Comment: i know it's about this app, what i am asking that can you please describe the feature you wanted to achieve using deeplink ? @HumbertoS.Ribeiro

Comment: just open the app

Comment: hi @HumbertoS.Ribeiro i've updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot!